# Redirect every third user to another page

Tags: javascript, html, load-balancing

I want to redirect every third user of my website to another page.
For example in js html

```
window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
```

The reason behind this need, is to attempt to load balance my traffic

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: just want to divide my traffic.

Comment: load balancer is your friend :)

Comment: Well, I'm reasonably certain doing what you want is impossible in Javascript alone. Javascript is client side, so it can't communicate with the client side portion of your website  on other computers without some interaction to the server.

Comment: Some more background is needed, for example why you think that using Javascript for this would be good, and how the fact that every user first loads one page and a third of them loads another page affects the site and the users.

Answer (score 3):

Every third user isn't possible without incorporating some kind of backend code on the server. But redirecting approximately one third of all visitors is possible.

```
if (Math.random() < 0.333333) window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
```